Trying to hide url bar from mobile application
I am stuck in bubble wrap the PWA application, all things going straight forward apk generated successfully but when it comes to validate the application(it establishes relationship between web and app through through sha256 fingerprints which is written in assetlinks. json  file) it fails, due to this my application shows the url bar which is not user friendly as it is a mobile application. If any one knows about bubble wrapping the PWA  please help me to get rid of this problem.
#bubblewrap #TWA #help #PWA #webapplication
Here I am trying to hide url bar from application(generated through bubble wrap). I am unable to done that.
